# custom string exercise in c++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I have a custom string class that uses an array of chars,

```
class MyString
{

private:
int length; 
char *chars; 

public:
MyString(const char* input)
{
    length = 0; 
    while (input[length] != '\0')
        ++length;

    chars = new char[length + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        chars[j] = input[j];
}
```

However when I use this class with a simple output I am getting a strange result in the console:

```
MyString newStr = "Test";
cout << newStr;
```

Gives me this output in the console:

Test═²²²²½½½½½½½½■ε■ε■ε■

This is with Visual Studio 2010 Win32 console app. I don't really know c++ very well and this is my first try at it.

Comment: Your first try should be with a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), do you have one?

Comment: You haven't shown the code that outputs the string. Show that.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put `\0` at the end of chars[]. `\0` is the character that MUST be put at the end of a char sequence. Otherwise, your program will output some random stuff (the bits after your array in memory) until it finds a `\0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop that copies `input` to `chars` isn't including the NUL terminator.  Change the loop condition to `j <= length` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I'd recommend:

1. You are not null terminating your chars[]
2. you need to overload the << operator.  Go to: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-friends/overload-io.html for an example.